# An example of arbitrage opportunity when LPs deposit assets in a pool

Tags: uniswap, arbitrage

I am studying about automated market making (Uniswap version **x*y=k**) for the first time and now I'm currently looking at liquidity pools.

Actually, I want to understand how the ratio of tokens' value in a pool relates to their prices in general. But, instead of trying to ask question about such a more general concept. I try to focus on the following text I've found in [this](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/concepts/core-concepts/pools) and [this](https://finematics.com/liquidity-pools-explained/).

> This first liquidity provider is the one who sets the initial price of the pool. They are incentivized to deposit an equal value of both tokens into the pool. To see why, consider the case where the first liquidity provider deposits tokens at a ratio different from the current market rate. This immediately creates a profitable arbitrage opportunity, which is likely to be taken by an external party.

> When a new pool is created, the first liquidity provider is the one that sets the initial price of the assets in the pool. The liquidity provider is incentivised to supply an equal value of both tokens to the pool. If the initial price of the tokens in the pool diverges from the current global market price, it creates an instant arbitrage opportunity that can result in lost capital for the liquidity provider.

Both of the sources say that if the first liquidity provider does not supply an *equal value* of both tokens to the pool, then there will be an arbitrage. Can anyone help explain why this is true? It would be great if someone could give an example with some tokens, their prices and simple calculation.

Thanks so much.

Comment: bro do u find a code. please help here